# Ruby error invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)

Tags: ruby, compiler-errors

I am trying to run the ruby script found [here](https://github.com/foobugs/foobugs-dashboard/blob/master/jobs/twitter_user.rb)

but I am getting the error

```
invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
```

for line 12 which is

```
http = Net::HTTP.new("twitter.com", Net::HTTP.https_default_port())
```

can someone please explain to me what this means and how I can fix it, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you run the script with Ruby 1.9, change the first two lines of the script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require 'net/http'
```

This tells Ruby to run the script with support for the `UTF-8` character set. Without that line Ruby 1.9 would default to the `US_ASCII` character set.

Just for the record: This will not work in Ruby 1.8, because 1.8 doesn't knew anything about string encodings. And the line is not needed anymore in Ruby 2.0, because Ruby 2.0 is using `UTF-8` as the default anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It means that a multibyte character is used and Ruby is not set to handle it. If you are using an old version of Ruby, then put the following magic comment at the beginning of the file:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

If you use a modern version of Ruby, then that problem would not arise in the first place.